# Jenkins doesn't recognized mounted driver

Tags: jenkins

i find out that Jenkins doesn't recognized mounted driver on the local computer (windows server 2012 R2).
is there any way to solve this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Jenkins is running as a user that has privileges to see and access the drive.
Also, you might need to restart Jenkins once the drive is mapped and accessible.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes jenkins usually logged with NT authority user , to map a drive from jenkins first go to execute window bach script and map here like:

subst X: M:\view\something

or

subst X: \view\folder

and after this post your script